# Rendering string in html template in FatFree

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I have a html file where fatfree renders html code from .html file. For example, The .html file has following code;

```
<include href='navigation.html'>
<include href='{{ @view }}>
```

where view contains path to .html file.

But in my case html code is generated by program as string type. How can I render such string as html in fatfree like.

```
<div>{{ @view }}</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/views-and-templates#Extendingfiltersandcustomtags

You can use filters to use the raw HTML code instead of an escaped (for security) version by using `<div>{{ @view|raw }}</div>`.

Alternatively you can disable escaping in general, which is highly discouraged.

`$f3->set('ESCAPE',FALSE);`